# I want to use drop table code with selecting a table name from another table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm selecting a table name 'id' and passing it to the next page. All my table names are stored in a table called 'rooms'. While running the following code, I need to drop the table safely.
This is my Sql query: `drop table (select t_name from rooms)`. Is it not possible to call like this...? Please help.

Here is my code:

```
'    int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("heading1"));'
`int i=0;'
'String sql="drop table (select room from rooms where id="+id+")";'
'ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);'
'i=ps.executeUpdate();'
```

Comment: First select the table name into a variable, then drop table "+ variable+"

Comment: That I know, but for that I need to write the sql query seperately, I want it together in same sql statement.Is that possible?